# Using wp config to connect to a DB from a plugin

Tags: plugins, query, mysql, wp-config

Im using the following to access tables information from my Wordpress DB

```
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
mysqli_select_db($conn, DB_NAME);
```

It works fine I'm able to connect and display the information. The trouble is when I try to do the same thing from a plugin within the Dashboard under tools, I get the following message:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant ABSPATH - assumed 'ABSPATH' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpressexpensereport\wp-content\plugins\editdb\connection.php
>   on line 2
>
> Warning: require_once(ABSPATHwp-config.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpressexpensereport\wp-content\plugins\editdb\connection.php
>   on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'ABSPATHwp-config.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpressexpensereport\wp-content\plugins\editdb\connection.php
>   on line 2

I have checked my wp config and I do have the following

```
    /** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Is there something I am missing with my implementation?

Thanks

Comment: Better to use WP Rest API. ;-)

Comment: Is there another solution that does not include WP Rest? From my understanding what i've illustrated should work. I think

Comment: Where exactly in your plugin do you use `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php');` ? Could it be that it's too early in the process, and wp-config.php has not loaded yet?

Comment: What are you trying to do that the `$wpdb` object will not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a custom "plugin" where you are wanting to run a file externally that connects to the WordPress database, not really as a standard plugin which loads within WordPress environment, as in that case as @belinus says you can just use `$wpdb` class.

Anyway, since `ABSPATH` is defined IN `wp-config.php`, you can't use `ABSPATH` to find and load `wp-config.php` - because it hasn't loaded and thus isn't defined yet. That's the flawed logic... hence the errors you are getting.

If you know for certain that `wp-config.php` is in a directory above where the "plugin" file is, you can do something like this:

```
function find_require($file,$folder=null) {
    if ($folder === null) {$folder = dirname(__FILE__);}
    $path = $folder.'/'.$file;
    if (file_exists($path)) {require($path); return $folder;}
    else {
        $upfolder = find_require($file,dirname($folder));
        if ($upfolder != '') {return $upfolder;}
    }
}
$configpath = find_require('wp-config.php');
```

This will recursively search for `wp-config.php` above the plugin file directory  and load it when it does. (Again this assumes the `wp-config.php` is located in a directory above the plugin file.)

Comment: Thank you for your response @majick, as well as everyone who contributed.  I've run into another issue related to this same plugin, not sure what prototcall is, continue on this thread or start a new one? Thanks

Comment: I think it really depends if it extends upon the existing topic (ie. path loading issues) or is unrelated, in which case I'd suggest post a new question.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably just missing the slash in the `require_once`. Change it to:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: `ABSPATH` should be defined with a trailing slash as can be seen in the code posted which is direct from a standard copy of `wp-config.php`